# Не работает Random

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Смотрю видеоурок по Random (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LVRvDVBiwUs) В примере задаётся диапазон чисел, от 1 до 6

```
System.out.println(random.nextInt(6) + 1);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сделал также, но у меня диапазон другой от 88 до 100

Код

```
Random random = new Random();
  Integer first = random.nextInt(100) + 88;
  System.out.println(first);
```

Результат - 142 ((

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Вы не так поняли идею. Надо размышлять так:

1. Диапазон необходимых чисел равен `МАСИМАЛЬНОЕ-МИНИМАЛЬНОЕ` число.
2. Т.к. ноль нам не нужен, а нужна 1 в качестве первого числа и максимальное число тоже нужно, то к диапазону надо добавить `1`
3. Т.к. сгенерированное число будет `от 0 до (МАСИМАЛЬНОЕ - МИНИМАЛЬНОЕ число + 1)`, то к полученному результату надо добавить минимальное число.

В итоге получится вот такой код:

```
int max = 100;
int min = 88;
int range = max - min + 1; // 13
int from0To12 = random.nextInt(range); // 0..12
int from88To100 = from0To12  + min; // 88..100
```